# Http client POST request xml+soap

Tags: scala, soap, xmlhttprequest

I want to make a post request in Scala to this API http://api.atinternet-solutions.com/toolbox/reporting.asmx
I first did it with a curl like this :

```
curl -X POST -T post.txt -H "Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8" http://api.atinternet-solutions.com/toolbox/reporting.asmx -v
```

and I got what I expected.

Now I want to call the API programatically with a simple HttpClient

```
val httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient()
def postRequest=new HttpPost("https://api.atinternet-solutions.com/toolbox/reporting.asmx")
postRequest.addHeader("Content-Type","application/soap+xml ; charset=utf-8")
postRequest.addHeader("SOAPAction","\"http://www.xiti.com/queryReport\"")
val file=new File("post.txt")
val fe=new FileEntity(file,"application/soap+xml;charset=utf-8")
postRequest.setEntity(fe)
val httpResponse=httpClient.execute(postRequest)
println(httpResponse.getStatusLine.toString)
val rspStr=Source.createBufferedSource(httpResponse.getEntity.getContent).mkString
println(rspStr)
```

but I get an HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
and printing the rspStr yields

```
"?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><soap:Code><soap:Value>soap:Receiver</soap:Value></soap:Code><soap:Reason><soap:Text xml:lang="en">Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Root element is missing.</soap:Text></soap:Reason><soap:Detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope"
```

The post.txt looks like below, except I set the good information instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Header>
    <NXHeader xmlns="http://www.xiti.com/">
      <GUID>string</GUID>
      <SecurityKey>string</SecurityKey>
      <Site>int</Site>
    </NXHeader>
  </soap12:Header>
  <soap12:Body>
    <queryReport xmlns="http://www.xiti.com/">
      <startDate>int</startDate>
      <endDate>int</endDate>
      <query>string</query>
      <param>string</param>
      <typereport>XML or CSV</typereport>
    </queryReport>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

The curl action which is working is done from my scala project directory. I printed post.txt in scala and got the good content.

I cannot figure out what is going wrong. Thank you for your help

Comment: What are the contents of post.txt?

Comment: Do you have right path to post.txt? Try opening it and reading from Scala.

Comment: @Jakozaur I opened post.txt in scala and read it. It works fine.

Comment: @Brian I added the content of the post.txt to my question

Comment: Did you try to test it with java code? Maybe the problem has something to do with the HTTPClient library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what was going wrong.
Replace

```
def postRequest
```

by

```
val postRequest.
```

Tks again

Answer (score 3):

I tried your call with the [dispatch library](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html).

This is my code

```
import dispatch._
import java.io.File

object ToolBox {

    val endpoint =  url("https://api.atinternet-solutions.com/toolbox/reporting.asmx").POST
        .addHeader("Content-Type","application/soap+xml ; charset=utf-8")
        .addHeader("SOAPAction",""" "http://www.xiti.com/queryReport" """)

    def report = Http( endpoint <<< new File("post.txt") > as.xml.Elem)

    def tryReport = {
        val res = report.either
        for {
            ex <- res.left
        } yield "Something got wrong " + ex.getMessage
    }

}
```

The service replies with a *status 500* like you, but the `faultString` in the response xml is: `A parameter is missing in your NXHeader or you have a namespace issue.`

Is it what you would expect, since the `post.txt` body contains only the placeholders from the [query report](http://api.atinternet-solutions.com/toolbox/reporting.asmx?op=queryReport) example, instead of real parameters?

Comment: I have real parameters in my post.txt but part of it is access token so I can't publish them online. Actually I found where the problem was (see my answer). Thank you for your help.